# What flag should I have used for a user reposting his question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

A new user posted the same question two times (here *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737514/open-files-from-a-network-shared-folder-using-php-in-a-xampp-server* and here *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745127/viewing-files-from-a-network-shared-folder-using-php-in-a-xampp-server*)

As there was nothing different between the two questions, I wanted to flag it to remove the duplicate question.

This is what I thought when choosing the flag:

- **Spam** => not suitable, this was not a question promoting something
- **Rude or abusive** => not suitable either
- **Duplicate** => yes, it is a duplicate, but the short description of this flag says "*This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*" As there is no answer on the first post, I did not use this flag
- **Off topic** => not suitable
- **Unclear** => IMO the question is quite clear so not suitable
- **Too broad** => I don't think so
- **Opinion based** => not suitable

So the last flag was "**In need of moderator intervention**: *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*" and this is the flag I used... and it was declined with this comment:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

So which flag should I have used?

Comment: There is an exception that allows duplicates to point to unanswered questions, *if* the author is the same in both. I guess it wouldn't hurt to update the text though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Duplicate would have been the correct flag.

While there is *usually* a requirement that a question have an answer before it becomes a dupe-target, this requirement does not exist if the questions are both from the same account. This exception exists mainly for this scenario: A new user (who likely doesn't quite understand how the site works) posting the same question twice.

Just flag the newer question as a dupe of the older, unless the newer question has more comments/involvement or is of higher quality. Then flag the older question.

Comment: OK, i'll remember this if i face this situation again

Comment: Also should mention quality as a factor too. Flag the worse question as a duplicate of the better one. Sometimes instead of editing, a user will repost with modifications since they don't know how the site works

Comment: IIRC I faced almost the same thing - two first questions from someone who joined within 24 hours, both using almost the same name. Since the referenced dupe didn't have an answer, the site sent an error, not a warning. Thus, I couldn't mark it as a duplicate. I ended up putting a comment in stating it was an *obvious* duplicate without flagging. Ti seems like a small hole in things - so it's okay to have two open questions without answers on the same thing? I'm on the Swift thread and am amazed at how many poor questions make it through. I guess that's the price for being a hot tag.

Comment: @dfd: The theory is that duping a new question against an old question which has no answers is unhelpful to both the asker and anyone who may be Googling the question.  The "correct" fix for this is to answer one of the questions and then dupe the other against it.  YMMV on whether that makes sense in any given scenario, though.

Comment: What if the older question is already itself closed? does that change anything here?