# New user makes a second account and reposts question, with added details

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation, duplicate-accounts

A new user makes their first post, it is missing a few details and a commenter asks for those details. Shortly after that a new post is made by a different new user with the same question and code, along with added details.

What is the right action to take here?

I suspect the user is very confused about the interface for whatever reason. Is this something I flag for a moderator to help them with or just ignore it unless they continue to do it?

I believe this question is different from *[What to do when someone keeps creating new accounts to ask the same bad question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278230/15497888)*, because the user improved the question.

[image]

Comment: close vote the older one as duplicate of the newer one

Comment: that makes prefect sense, now if only i had not already voted to close the old post for needing details

Comment: Related about same account reposts: [What flag should I have used for a user reposting his question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341975/15497888), [1 user reposting same question over and over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255371/15497888)

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably VTC (gold badge in the tags in active in) the new one and then propagate changes to the old one. This includes if the old question is closed, as reposting to get around closure shouldn't be endorsed; though I may well vote to reopen their old question of the improvement is good enough

Comment: Here's a similar one as well about creating new accounts to ask the same question [What to do when someone keeps creating new accounts to ask the same bad question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278230/15497888)

Comment: @Larnu don't we in general, keep the better question? Now you have to do busy work.

Comment: Personally, I don't know, it's just how I probably would have. Is there a conanical saying otherwise, @rene ?

Comment: I overlooked the problem that the user created a new account.

Comment: @Larnu answer on MSE from a former SE employee: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281977/shouldnt-the-newer-questions-be-marked-as-duplicate-and-not-the-earlier-ones/281979#281979 it doesn't get more canonical then that ... ;)

Comment: That talks about better *answers* @rene . Not duplicate from the same user, with additional content.

Comment: @Larnu well, this one then: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Comment: [Just flag it for moderator attention. They can see more data/info etc than we can.](/a/278232/15497888) seems to be the answer to this question even if the circumstances are different. There's nothing a normal user can do to handle this  as the duplicate closure without answers exception does not apply for different accounts. The separate account to circumvent a rate limit is also something a moderator should be made aware of.

Comment: If you suspect same user/different account I would also flag it so the moderators can check/ensure one isn't acting as a sock-puppet for the other. (though with the obvious reversal of order of names, that's probably unlikely here)

Comment: The title could also say "User lost credentials to his old account, repost the same question with added details". This scenario isn't so uncommon, so presuming some sort of malice is unwarranted at this point of time.

Comment: @Braiam I do not believe the current title assumes malice, it simply states 3 things. 1 there is a new your (who I assume the same as another new user) 2 they have posted the same question, 3 they added requested details to the reposted question. If I believed there was malice or intent to circumvent some rule I would have just flagged it without question. But it seemed to me like the user was simply confused

Comment: I mean, look at the comments, people already presume malice.

Comment: True, however i do not think that is driven by the title as much as it is by the general bias to see the malice in this "questionable" behavior. I don't know that it would be appropriate to assumed the reason the user made a new account, which saying `User lost credentials` would strongly imply I know that for a fact was why they did it, and I do not.

Comment: @Nifim right you are. We curate content, not people. So we are not out to do witch hunts. We just look out for objects mysteriously floating about and that is what we report.